# Access the value of variable outside its scope

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to access a variable which was in another function. The variable to be accessed and accessing functions are same class,SAME PROJECT BUT DIFFERENT FUNCTIONS. Also,without global variable declaration

```
protected void gdDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       int dbCompany = Convert.ToInt32(gdDisplay.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
}
void gvFunction_Update()
{
       //place to access dbcompany variable//
}
```

Comment: you cant, but if you explain why you need this we might be able to find a way around it

Comment: you cannot access them like that. What are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 1):

Create a private property "DbCompany" in the class to access the variable through the property

```
private int DbCompany {get;set;}

protected void gdDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       int dbCompany = Convert.ToInt32(gdDisplay.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
       //This is where the property gets its value 
       DbCompany = dbCompany; 
 }
void gvFunction_Update()
{
   //place to access dbcompany variable//
   //Get the value from DbCompany;
   int dbcompany = DbCompany;
}
```

If you make the property "public", you could even access the value outside the class and "protected" if you want to be able to access it by child classes.

I believe using properties is a better way to go. I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access that since `dbCompany` is a local variable in `gdDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged` method. You will have to declare a global variable at class level instead:-

```
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    int dbCompany = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Page Load event
    }
    protected void gdDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbCompany = Convert.ToInt32(gdDisplay.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
    }
    void gvFunction_Update()
    {
        int x = dbCompany ;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What about modify function signature to void `void gvFunction_Update(int something)` and pass dbCompany as parameter?

Comment: @GianPaolo - That depends on the requirement, if OP want to call the method from  `gdDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged` then it's fine but OP never mentioned this.